# Give a warning for calling an Apple Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, warnings, presentviewcontroller

This is a very interesting problem that I have. My app had an issue with `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`. What happened is the presentViewController gets called, and based off of server information, it's possible that the View Controller will be dismissed. I would get an error saying "Can't dismiss before it's fully presented" (Animation is set to YES).

I implemented a queue to handle the present, and dismiss calls. This works perfect, and I'm really happy with this solution. Then I realized another problem, what if I accidentally call Apple's methods directly (I have a method called `myPresentViewController:animated:completion:`, and `myDismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` that handle the queuing).

Is there a way for me to set up a warning method if I call Apple's methods directly? I've tried creating a Category (I've also tried an Extension), defining Apple's present, and dismiss methods, and adding a deprecated message to them. Neither of these ways worked. I've thought about swizzling the methods, but that doesn't work because if the swizzled method adds it to the queue, how will it know when to call apple's implementation? I realize that the warning will show up in the one spot where I need to call Apple's method, but I can use #pragma to inhibit warnings for the two lines I need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view controller base class that extends `UIViewController`. Then make sure all of your view controllers extend this base class. Do the same for `UITableViewController` if needed.

In these base classes you can implement the two methods and add your deprecation flag to the method declarations in the .h file.

TGViewController.h

```
@interface TGViewController : UIViewConrtoller

- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(5_0, 6_0);
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^)(void))completion NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(5_0, 6_0);

@end
```

TGViewController.m

```
@implementation TGViewController

- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
}

- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^)(void))completion {
    [super dismissControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
}

@end
```

No pragmas needed.

You can also use these base classes to add any other app-level features you might want.